# How to select unique values only in one field in an Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007

I have looked several places on how to have a single distinct column while displaying other related data to the unique field. All of the examples I have seen only involve a single table and a handful of fields which isn't applicable to my situation (see code below). Currently I am using the max function to narrow down the number of selected records, but it is still leaving duplicates in the `[Part Group Nbr]` column which I need to have be unique values only. All I need is representative data from each `[Part Group Nbr]`. I have also done a side query using the `SELECT DISTINCT` function to get a unique list of just the `[Part Group Nbr]` field but I can't figure out any meaningful way to join it to the query.

`SELECT Reps.[Logistics Rep], Max([Supplier Link].[Supplier Name]) AS [Supplier Name], Max([Supplier Link].[Supplier Nbr]) AS [Supplier Nbr], Max([Part Number].[Loc #]) AS [Loc #], Max([Part Number].[Part Nbr]) AS [Part Nbr], Max([Part Number].[Part Name]) AS [Part Name], Max([Part Number].[Part Group Nbr]) AS [Part Group Nbr], Max([Part Number].[RCM Pack Nbr]) AS [RCM Pack Nbr], Max([Part Number].[Part Status]) AS [Part Status], Max([Part Number].[Project Type]) AS [Project Type], Max([Part Number].[Pack Rank]) AS [Pack Rank], Max([Part Number].[Pack Container]) AS [Pack Container], Max([Part Number].[Pack Quantity]) AS [Pack Quantity], Max(E0.[Drawing Review]) AS [Drawing Review], Max(E0.[Part/Pack Ranking & VSM]) AS [Part/Pack Ranking & VSM], Max(E0.DIS) AS DIS, Max(E0.[Pre Concept]) AS [Pre Concept], Max(E0.[E-0 Status]) AS [E-0 Status], Max(E1.[OEM Impact Study]) AS [OEM Impact Study], Max(E1.[Concept Activity]) AS [Concept Activity], Max(E1.[E-1 Status]) AS [E-1 Status], Max(E2.Prototype) AS Prototype, Max(E2.[NAPS/PIFs]) AS [NAPS/PIFs], Max(E2.[Mass Pro Bid]) AS [Mass Pro Bid], Max(E2.[Mass Pro Selection]) AS [Mass Pro Selection], Max(E2.[PO/Budget Application]) AS [PO/Budget Application], Max(E2.[Quality Confirmation]) AS [Quality Confirmation], Max(E2.[E-2 Status]) AS [E-2 Status], [Part Number].[Base 5], Max(Left([Part Number].[Part Nbr],8)) AS [base 8], Max(Left([Part Number].[Part Nbr],11)) AS [Base 10]`

`FROM ((((Reps INNER JOIN [Supplier Link] ON Reps.[Logistics Rep] = [Supplier Link].[Logistics Rep]) INNER JOIN [Part Number] ON [Supplier Link].[Supplier Name] = [Part Number].[Supplier Name]) INNER JOIN ([Unique parts List] INNER JOIN E0 ON [Unique parts List].[Part Nbr] = E0.[Part Nbr]) ON [Part Number].[Part Nbr] = [Unique parts List].[Part Nbr]) INNER JOIN E1 ON [Unique parts List].[Part Nbr] = E1.[Part Nbr]) INNER JOIN E2 ON [Unique parts List].[Part Nbr] = E2.[Part Nbr]`

`WHERE ((([Part Number].[Project Type])="NEW" Or ([Part Number].[Project Type])="MOT" Or ([Part Number].[Project Type])="MOF"))`

`GROUP BY Reps.[Logistics Rep], [Part Number].[Base 5]`

`HAVING (((Max([Part Number].[Pack Rank]))="AR" Or (Max([Part Number].[Pack Rank]))="AV" Or (Max([Part Number].[Pack Rank]))="AC" Or (Max([Part Number].[Pack Rank]))="BR" Or (Max([Part Number].[Pack Rank]))="BE" Or (Max([Part Number].[Pack Rank]))="BV"));`

Comment: There is an error in you joins `INNER JOIN ([Unique parts List] INNER JOIN E0 ON [Unique parts List].[Part Nbr] = E0.[Part Nbr]) ON [Part Number].[Part Nbr] = [Unique parts List].[Part Nbr])`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an error - it runs fine as is and it's actually the code generated by Access when I make the query (just did it again to be sure). When I try to "fix" it, it starts throwing errors.